# WP REST API and Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: api, cache, rest-api, wp-api, plugin-wp-supercache

In one of my project I use a Wordpress REST Api. When I was enabled cache by WP Super Cache plugin I have an error now:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.mydomain.com/wp-json/wp/v1/posts. Origin http://mydomaintwo.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I found a `.htaccess` solution, but I will be happy if anyone know a working PHP solution.

It's my .htaccess with multiple domain access support and access for only GET request:

```
# CORS Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(localhost:8080|example\.com|example\.net)$" origin_is=$0 
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, content-type"
</ifModule>


# BEGIN WordPress
... # default WP rules
# END WordPress


# CORS OPTIONS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

If you want to use only one domain, you can remove the line starts with "SetEnvIf...", and in the next put:

`Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://example.com"`

If you want to use also other request, you can separated it by a comma:

`Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"`